# How to unmount a drive in Windows using cmd

Tags: partitioning

I recently tried to install rEFInd and created a drive S: with mountvol S: /S. I want to unmount this drive but doing mountvol S: /P says The system cannot find the file specified. I can't access that drive with Explorer as it says that I don't have permission to access it. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you run the command with administrator privileges? Have you checked the EventLog? Maybe you will find some answers there.

Comment: This should be a comment.